# How to set singleton class of MKMapView as the map in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, mkmapview, uistoryboard

I created a singleton class of `MKMapView` that I use across many classes to turn on and off `showsUserLocation` and tracking methods. The code seems to work on the singleton class; however, it has no effect on the actual map in the simulator. I believe that the `MKMapView` in the `Storyboard` is not actually the instance of the Singleton class, even though I changed its class in the Interface Builder Custom Class category, and created an `IBOutlet` to it. How can I make sure the map in the `Storyboard` is the same map that my code is affecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the `initWithCoder:` method. This is the method that is called to unarchive a class from the storyboard.

```
static MyMapView *map = nil;

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (map) {
        return map;
    }
    else {
        @synchronized (self) {
            if (!map) {
                map = [super initWithCoder:coder];
            }
            return map;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I have never implemented this so it may need tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

```
class var GsharedInstance: GoogleMap {
    struct Static {
        static let instance: GoogleMap = GoogleMap()
    }
    return Static.instance
}
```

Easy Way in Swift